# Google Analytics Events Tracking with Echo

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to track onclick event to track a button on my site but I'm not too familiar with PHP.

Here's an example of how the code looks like on my site:

```
<a href="<?php if($clang=='en') { echo "http://www.website.com/english/"; } 
else {
echo "http://www.website.com/news/"; } ?>" class="xyz_<?php echo $clang; ?>">News Button</a>
```

I need to add this code below to track when users click on the "News Button" image:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banner', 'click', 'News Button']);"
```

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: did you try just adding that onclick to the a tag and seeing if it logs correctly? By the way, this has nothing to do with php

Comment: hi Kai. I didn't add the code at all. I know normally it would look like this: `<a href="http://www.website.com/news/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banner', 'click', 'News Button']);">News Button</a>` but I don't see how to add it there.

Comment: I updated. You are right in how you add it. You may just be getting confused by the presence of php in there. The html is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo $clang == 'en' ? "http://www.website.com/english/" : "http://www.website.com/news/"; ?>" class="xyz_<?php echo $clang; ?>" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banner', 'click', 'News Button']);">News Button</a>
```

That would be the quick way to add it. Let me know if you need anything clarified.
I condensed your php to be handled by a ternary operator. No need for that if statement the way it was.

Comment: Thanks Kai. Looks like the right format. Do I need to escape those single quotes? like this? \'_trackEvent\', \'banner', \'click\', \'News Button\' or no?

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm without the escape.